# Getting Massive generated possible words

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I want to create every possible character available in a sequence 
Such as `aa` `ab` and so on until `Aa456&bGgha*#` until `15 char`
My set:

```
string_all=[
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','.',
    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
    ]
data = open('generator.txt','w+')
```

My first idea is to use `recursion`
 The idea failed because its kinda weird to do it?

```
def the_input(num,array):
    for x in range(0,len(string_all)):
        array.append(string_all[x])
        print("".join(array))
        array.remove(array[num])

def the_start():
    for i in range(0,len(string_all)):
        text=[]
        text.append(string_all[i])
        for y in range(1,len(string_all)):
            the_input(y,text)
```

I stopped here as soon i realized i need to get back to the `the_start()` but without other `funtion` disturb it
 My second attempt:

```
def start():
    text = []
    for i in range(0,len(string_all)):
        text.append(string_all[i])
        data.write(text[i])
    text = sequence(text)

def sequence(letter):
    temp = []
    for i in range(0,len(letter)):
        for x in range(0,len(string_all)):
            letter[i] = letter[i]+string_all[x]

    return letter
```

i stopped because i realized i need to do a `list within a list` to achieve this
 And so i came up with this `messy`,`bulky`,`not pretty` and `super not efficient` code:

```
def main():
    for x in string_all:
        data.write(x+"\n")
    for x in string_all:
        for y in string_all:
            data.write(x+y+"\n")
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                data.write(a+b+c+"\n")
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    data.write(a+b+c+d+"\n")
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        data.write(a+b+c+d+e+"\n")
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        for f in string_all:
                            data.write(a+b+c+d+e+f+"\n")
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        for f in string_all:
                            for g in string_all:
                                data.write(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+"\n")    
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        for f in string_all:
                            for g in string_all:
                                for h in string_all:
                                    data.write(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+"\n")   
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        for f in string_all:
                            for g in string_all:
                                for h in string_all:
                                    for i in string_all:
                                        data.write(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+"\n")   
    for a in string_all:
        for b in string_all:
            for c in string_all:
                for d in string_all:
                    for e in string_all:
                        for f in string_all:
                            for g in string_all:
                                for h in string_all:
                                    for i in string_all:
                                        for j in string_all:
                                            data.write(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+"\n")
```

It's kinda work for the `4 char` but getting super `not efficient` 
I used `google colab` and the result is still not fast..is there any other approach that i does not know?

Comment: You can use `itertools.product`.  Beware that your generated char `list` of string/word may be blow your system memory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AmirulAkmal, you could try this as your working `template` to get what you want.   The idea is to generate various length of strings based on your `input string`.

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain, product

import string   # for string.ascii_letters, string.digits

# For demo purpose
s = 'dairy'

def generate_strings(s, sizes):

    return list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, size) for size in sizes))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sizes = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    for item in generate_strings(s, sizes):
        print(''.join(item))
 
# Output:
d
a
i
r
y
da
di
dr
dy
ai
ar
ay
ir
iy
ry
dai
dar
day
dir
diy
dry
air
aiy
ary
iry
dair
daiy
dary
diry
airy
```

Comment: This is the most perfect solution i've ever had...Very Much Appreciate it and keep it up

Comment: Glad that I can help. Keep learning and practicing ... Welcome to S/O q-n-a.